# Verification of a peculiar Banach space.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, lp-spaces

Suppose $H$ is the space of absolute continuous functions $f$, and both $f$ and $f'$ are in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$. And the norm is defined as:
$$\|f\|=\sqrt{\int_{\mathbb{R}}|f|^2\mathrm{d} x+\int_{\mathbb{R}}|f'|^2\mathrm{d} x}$$
I'm trying to prove it's a Banach space with the standard method, which is, find the limit of an arbitrary Cauchy sequence$\{f_n\}$.
Here is my attempt.

First, both $f_n$ and $f_n'$ should converges to a function in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$(denoted by $f$ and $\tilde{f}$ respectively), and $\int_{a}^b \tilde{f}\mathrm{d}x=f(a)-f(b)$ should hold almost everywhere. But I'm stuck here.

At first I thought it could be proved that $\forall f$ that is absolutely continuous and integrable satisfies $f(-\infty)=0$, yet I constructed a counterexample soon; similiarly, I constructed a Cauchy sequence that is nowhere pointwise convergent.

So now I have no clue and any kind of hint or help would be very useful.

Comment: i think a Cauchy sequence must be pointwise convergent, in fact convergent in a Holder space, what is your example? PS you may find some books studying this peculiar space under the name of a ‘Sobolev space’

Comment: So we have a example of a sequence of functions that is convergent in measure and nowhere pointwise convergent on a interval, say, [0,1]: f_{2^n+i}=\sin{2^{n-1}\pi x}\mathcal{X}_{[\frac{i}{2^n},\frac{i+1}{2^{n+1}}]}. For other intervals [m,m+1], just translate the original function on it and mutiply it with a $2^{-m}$. Then the sequence converges to $g\equiv 0$ in the sense of $2$-norm, but is nowhere pointwise convergent.

Comment: It seems easier to just make your counterexample vanish outside of [0,1] to achieve the same result. And I don’t believe the sequence of derivatives is convergent to 0 in L^2. So it won’t be cauchy in H

Comment: Vanishing outside of $[0,1]$ makes it converge at $-1$, which is no longer a counterexample, but you are right that the derivatives does not belong to $L^2$ and I will look up for Sobolev Spaces in other books, thank you.

Comment: Sure yes I forgot you were looking for nowhere pointwise convergence. Yw

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out lately and my friend also gave a solution.

My solution:

$\forall a,b$, $f_n,f_n'$ converge in $L^2[a,b]$, so in $L^1[a,b]$ to $f,\tilde{f}$. So $\lim\limits_n\int_{[a,x]}f_n\mathrm{d} m=\lim\limits_n(f_n(x)-f_n(a))=\int_{[a,x]}\tilde{f}\mathrm{d}m$. Therefore $\{g_n(x)=f_n(x)-f_n(a)\}$ converge pointwise\uniformly\in the sense of $L^1$ on $[a,b]$, $\{h_n(x)=f_n(x)-g_n(x)\equiv f_n(a)\}$ converge in $L^1[a,b]$. Therefore $\{f_n(x)\}$ converges pointwise in $[a,b]$. So $\lim\limits_n(f_n(b)-f_n(a))=f(b)-f(a)=\int_{[a,b]}\tilde{f}\mathrm{d}m$, $f\in H$ and $f'=\tilde{f}$. $\|f-f_n\|\leq (\|f-f_n\|_2+\|f'-f'_n\|_2)\rightarrow 0$

My friend's solution:

$\forall h\in H$, $x\in \mathbb{R}$, $\exists x_0< x\ s.t.|h(x_0)|\leq \frac{|h(x)|}{2}$(otherwise it won't be integrable). Therefore $\|h\|\geq \sqrt{\int_{x_0}^x|h|^2\mathrm{d}m+\int_{x_0}^x|h'|^2\mathrm{d}m}\geq\sqrt{(\int_{x_0}^x|h|^2\mathrm{d}m\int_{x_0}^x|h'|^2\mathrm{d}m)^\frac{1}{2}}\geq\sqrt{\int_{x_0}^x|h·h'|\mathrm{d}m}\geq\sqrt{|h^2(x)-h^2(x_0)|}\geq \sqrt{\frac{3}{4}}|h(x)|$.

Replace $h$ with $f_n-f$, we reach the conclusion that $\{f_n\}$ converges uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$. The rest would be natural.

It's the uniformly convergent part that shocks me, I think it's because the convergence of derivative does not 'allow' the original function to bounce over anywhere. And we can conclude that convergent in the sense of this norm is stronger than convergent in the sense of $L^\infty$ norm.

Comment: good job, in fact the functions are also automatically in a (Banach) space of Hölder continuous functions. $H$ is not that peculiar :)

Comment: Oh, as I recall Holder continuous function is like the general version of Lipschitz function, so in this case is the '$\alpha$' ($|f(x)-f(y)|<C|x-y|^\alpha$) related to the original $L^p$ space we choose(here $p=2$)?

Comment: Yes, I believe its  $\alpha = 1 - 1/p$ for $W^{1,p}$ (i.e. $f,f' \in L^p$)

Comment: Okay I will check on that, thanks!